# While and file_exists in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, header, file-exists

I have this code on php:

```
while (!file_exists(test.txt)) sleep(1); //wait for test.txt (in the same path)
header("Location:loading.php"); //proceed with the next page
```

But it doesn't work.

It stays in a loop, even with the file correctly generated.

I only want that once he finds the file, he continues with the header, but does not continue until then.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you forget quotes? `file_exists('test.txt')`

Comment: And you may also need to provide the full path name.

Comment: Scary code you got going here ;)

Comment: tested but problem persist too. Thanks.

Comment: You need to be forthcoming of your full file path in relation to the php that is executing this code. Otherwise it's anyones guess.

Comment: show me more codes what you have done .

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the filename in quotation marks in order for the `file_exists` function to properly read it. You may also need to specify the full path of the file.

Try it this way:

```
while (!file_exists('/path/to/test.txt')) sleep(1); //wait for test.txt (in the same path)
header("Location:loading.php"); //proceed with the next page
```

Comment: tested but problem persist too. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is being created within the execution time limit?

Answer (score 0):

If i do:

```
   if (!file_exists('test.txt')){ 
    usleep(7000000); 
    } 
    else { 
    header("Location:loading.php"); 
    } 
header("Location:loading.php");
```

It works, but i must wait 7 seconds... I want go header, when file exists (without fixed time for waiting). But with while, it doesn't work.

Comment: This will only perform the check once. If the file doesn't exist in that 7 seconds, it will continue regardless of whether the file exists at that point or not.

Comment: I know. For that reason I want a loop that check it.